# could not \ specific past events

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal

Correct the sentence

- I could not use my car yesterday because it was being repaired.

I understand that the sentence is grammatical as it is or with *was not able to*

Many grammar books suggest that using *could* (positive form) is not possible but it is possible to use the negative form of could.  Yet, anywhere you go, you can find duplicate idea!

Some writers would use a specific technique likely a trick to separate the adverb ‘yesterday’

- Yesterday, I could not use my car…

Comment: It's not always wrong to use _could_ in the past tense (_I could hear him but I couldn't hear you_), but people may avoid sentences like _I could use my car yesterday_ because _could_ is often used to make a suggestion. _I could take you in my car if yours is out of action_.

Comment: @KateBunting: Do you *really* think any native speakers might "avoid" saying things like *Before ULEZ I could drive into London to visit friends whenever I wanted* (in favour of *Before ULEZ I **was able to** drive into London...*)? That sounds to me like something which might bother nns, but surely not us natives!

Comment: The choice of tense is often slightly different with a time phrase, which eliminates ambiguity and means you don't have to choose the precise best tense, and "Before ULEZ I could drive into London to visit friends whenever I wanted" has two phrases/clauses specifying the time. On its own "I could drive into London to visit friends" suggests more like a present thought than a statement about the past.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I was trying to rationalise the OP's assertion that 'grammar books suggest using _could_ in the positive form is not possible'.

Comment: @KateBunting: Yeah - I guessed from your *people may avoid...* that you didn't necessarily endorse that position. Presumably the OP isn't just making up that business about *Many grammar books suggest using could ( positive form ) is not possible,* but it doesn't ring any bells with me, so I wonder if the OP has actually *misunderstood* something. Just because *I could do that* could refer to past *or* present ability doesn't seem like a reason to avoid using it (let's face it - how often would context fail to clearly disamabiguate *that* aspect, if indeed it mattered?).

Comment: ...after all, surely no-one avoids saying ***I quit**!* just because people might not know whether they're *currently* quitting, or reporting something that they did in the past!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Outstanding point on *I quit*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be based on the mistaken idea that there is some reason why native speakers might avoid using non-negated "could" in past tense constructions. If we knew *why* the OP has that erroneous idea, we might usefully be able to explain why s/he's misunderstood something. Without that information there doesn't seem to be a meaningful question here.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to speak of past ability using could or "was able"

> I could use my car yesterday.

> I was able to use my car yesterday.

You might choose the second to avoid some of the other senses of "could", such as in conditional expressions. But remember no sentence stands alone, and there is always some context. The word "yesterday" provides some of that context.

> I could use my car but I'd rather walk.  (in this context "could" is used in a conditional sense)

In the negative both are possible:

> I couldn't use my car yesterday.

> I wasn't able to use my car yesterday.

In questions, the "could" form tends to be used for permission,

> Could I use my car? (asking for permission)

> Could you use your car? (interpretation depends on context)

> Was I able to use my car? (asking about ability)

Comment: You did not come on the question sentence. You tried your own examples and you avoid yourself away not to negotiate ?   Can you say "  I could use my car yesterday " ?

Comment: Yes you can say "I could use my car yesterday"

Comment: But many grammar books tell using the positive form = ( not possible  )? This is not possible with short-term abilities:
*Yesterday, I could go to work.
unless it occurs with verbs of perception:
When I opened the door I could hear nothing.
or in reported speech:
He asked if there was somewhere they could talk in private.
But there is no restriction on could not referring to the past:
Yesterday, I couldn’t go to work.
In situations where could cannot be used to refer to a past ability, the semi-modal be able
to can be used:
You were able to go to work yesterday.

Comment: "Yesterday I could go to work" is correct English.  It mean the same as Yesterday I was able to go to work.

Comment: Sorry, but your example  " I could use my car yesterday." = not correct   Read the explanation blew I stated  from Oxford Guide to English Grammar - Page 125   >> To tell you the truth    "I don't know why ".  I still try hard to focus on and to find the reason why  ?

Comment: I see it is possible when introduce a sentence by ( yesterday ) and insert a comma behind Yesterday, I could go to work = possible \ I could go to work yesterday = not common or not acceptable ? That's the reason I came and tried to focus on  this matter of grammar Here I also found in Oxford Guide to English Grammar - Page 125 But we use was/were able to to talk about an action in a particular situation, when someone had the ability to do something and did it. The injured man was able to walk to a phone box. NOT The injured man could walk to a phone box.

Comment: @AhmadMohammad **I could use my car yesterday** is also correct because it means the  speaker had the possibility/opportunity (or someone's permission) to use a car. It is NOT specifically referring to *ability*.

Answer (score 0):

> I could not use my car yesterday because it was being repaired.

*I could not / was not able to use my car yesterday because*…
= both forms are right  (*could* in negative form can be used)

- I could use my car yesterday (NO)
- I was able to use my car yesterday (YES)

As far as I know,  grammar books conclude:

There is no restriction on *could not* referring to the past:

> Yesterday, I couldn’t go to work. (YES)

In situations where *could* cannot be used to refer to a past ability, the semi-modal *be able to* can be used:

> You were able to go to work yesterday. (YES)

Comment: Reference :  From words to Grammar and many other books :  This is not possible with short-term abilities:
*Yesterday, I could go to work.
unless it occurs with verbs of perception:
When I opened the door I could hear nothing.
or in reported speech:
He asked if there was somewhere they could talk in private.
But there is no restriction on could not referring to the past:
Yesterday, I couldn’t go to work.
In situations where could cannot be used to refer to a past ability, the semi-modal be able
to can be used:
You were able to go to work yesterday

Comment: Another reference ( An Introduction to English Grammar Syntax)  :   But to say that someone had the ability to do something, and he did it in a particular situation, or a specific single event, we must use (was / were able to)  could is not possible 
He fell down but he was able to walk home.
They were able to drive safely despite the heavy rain. 
Could not (couldn't) is used to express both general ability and ability in particular situations: 
Peter couldn't drive. Peter couldn't meet Mr. Johns yesterday.

Comment: Another reference : Oxford Guide to English Grammar - Page 125  >> But we use was/were able to to talk about an action in a particular situation, when
someone had the ability to do something and did it.
The injured man was able to walk to a phone box.
NOT The injured man could walk to a phone box.

Comment: Oxford  : Could and was/were able to    For a general ability we use could or was/were able to.
Kevin could walk/was able to walk when he was only eleven months old.
But we use was/were able to to talk about an action in a particular situation, when
someone had the ability to do something and did it.
The injured man was able to walk to a phone box.
NOT The injured man could walk to a phone box.
We can also express the meaning with managed to or succeeded in.
Detectives were able to/managed to identify the murderer.
Detectives succeeded in identifying the murderer.